# Placing specifically placed images in a div -HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place 5 little circle images over one image but the circles need to be in specific spots. How would I do that where it would also be scaleable? I already have most of the page built except for this one part.

I tried wrapping it all in one div, then using padding and/or margins on the circles to place them correctly, but I can't seem to get everything correct and they move when being scaled down.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is your friend. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Use percentage units for your placement of the circles

Comment: please post the code - it's hard to help with nothing to go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly you must post some code here or on jsfiddle.net or codepen . so that we can see what you have tried and what you are asking for.

secondly I am answering your question without knowing what you have tried so it may or may not be the answer of your question.

solution--

1. take div and use position absolute for positioning the circles .
2. you can use id or class for each circle an position them .
3. now for every circle use eg:-transform: scale(2,3); property to scale the image on hover or whatever you want.

hope this may help you. but do post your code here for better assistance

Comment: Sorry for not posting any code! This did work though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a `<div class="primaryImage"></div>`
2. Then in `<style>` or your CSS file: `.primaryImage { background: url(path/img.png) no-repeat; position: relative; }`
3. Now make your circles `<img class="circle" src="path/circle.gif"/>` and place them **inside** `.primaryImage`
4. Then in the same place as #2: `.circle { position: absolute; }`
5. Assign an id* to each circle.
      Example: `<img`**id="c1"**`class="circle" src="path/circle.gif"/>`
6. After you have assigned a unique id to each circle `<img>` assign the following style rules as you did in #2 and #4:

   ```
    #c1 { top: 0; left: 0; } /* Top left corner */

    #c2 { bottom: 0; left: 0; } /*Bottom left corner */

    #c3 { bottom: 0; right: 0; } /* Bottom right corner */

    #c4 { top: 0; right: 0; } /* Top right corner */

    #c5 { top: 50%; left: 50%; } /* center */
   ```

*All classes and ids are arbitrary as well as the `top, bottom, left,` and `right` properties, they can be anything you want.